# Probability when spinning a disk

Tags: probability

A player spins a disk with three regions. The first region has the number 3. The second region has the number 5. The 3rd region has the number 4.

On every spin, each of the numbered sections has a equal chance of stopping at the arrow marker. If c is the 1st result, and d is the 2nd result, what is the probability that c + d will be odd?

Comment: Our event happens if we get odd then even or even then odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ outcomes for 2 spins. This is so small, you can just count how many of the 9 outcomes give you an odd sum. Or, you can go with the hint in a comment and count how many ways the first spin is odd and the second spin is even, and then the total number out of the 9 outcomes that give an odd sum is twice this number.